# Force rotation of a UIViewController in a NavigationController in a TabbarController

Tags: objective-c, ios, rotation, landscape, portrait

I've got my View hierarchy set up like this.

```
UITabBarController
    |
    UINavigationController
    |  |
    |  UIViewController
    |
    UINavigationController
       |
       UIViewController
```

The thing is that I have a ViewController that is only shown in Portrait, as soon as I turn the device to landscape another ViewController is being pushed on top, that is working as intended so far.

What I want now is that as soon as I push the back button on the newly popped ViewController  that the old ViewController is being forced to Portrait, even though the Device is still in Landscape.
I have tried it with transitions, but then the other views are getting screwed and don't properly recognize there orientation anymore leading to a mess of displaced views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that worked for me was using

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

in my ViewController and presenting it with ***presentModalViewController***.
This forces the View to stay in landscape.
Not exactly what I wanted, but it worked out.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your original view controller:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation)) return YES;
    return NO;
}
```

This should force it to only display in portrait orientation.

Comment: Sadly that's not working either. As the device is already in landscape mode it probably thinks: "well, then I'll stay in landscape as it is". The only thing that happens is that the transition animation between these two views is wrong (top to bottom instead from right to left)

Comment: You may well be right, I've only ever used this with a modal view controller.

Answer (score 1):

The code below will force the view into landscape mode, but only if the parent view controller supports landscape mode.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

If the parent view controller of the view you want to force into landscape mode is portrait only, you'll have to create a new new navigation controller. The easiest way to do that is just presenting the forced-landscape view controller in a modal view. So use presentModalViewController instead of pushViewController.